# Checking for open files in a given directory tree

Tags: c++, windows, ntfs, refs, apimonitor

Is there a way to determine with C+++ if any file is open in a given directory tree?

`Cmd.exe` knows instantly if I attempt to rename a folder and a file within that directory tree is currently open. I've used API Monitor to determine that cmd.exe uses `NtOpenFile()` followed by `NtSetInformationFile` with `FileRenameInformation` and that returns `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` when a file is open but I've not been able to determine what's happening at a lower level.

I'm trying to ensure no files are open before beginning a batch process without having to check each file individually as there could be hundreds of thousands of files in the directory tree.

Can anyone expand on this?

Thanks,
Steve Thresher.

Comment: If you need to do this from the CMD command line, you can use Microsoft's [SysInternal Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) by Mark Russinovich, which also can tell you the process that has a lock on a file in a directory.  If you need to do it programmatically yourself, Paul's answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check each file individually, I think.  That said, this should do it:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile
    (my_filename, GENERIC_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError ();
    if (err == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION)
    {
        // File is already open
    }
}
else
    CloseHandle (hFile);
```

Note that `dwShareMode` is passed as `0`, which prevents Windows opening the file if it is already opened elsewhere.